# Inno Setup: How to launch Adobe Reader and display a PDF

Tags: pdf, installation, inno-setup

I am trying to launch Adobe Reader at the end of the install to display a readme file.  I am using PDF because I need to display some images.  My inno setup script is failing with "Unable to execute file:  Create Process failed; code 267, the directory name is invalid."

I have tried with and without quote around Filename:  The path has spaces, however, reading the documentation, inno will take care of path with spaces (is that correct?).

BTW - Adobe is installed (or the user has to install it before installing the application)  In my case it is already installed.

The code snipet that I am using:

```
[Tasks]
Name: StartAfterInstall; Description: Display the PDF Readme File

[Run]
Filename: "{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe,@AcroRd32.exe} {app}\readme.pdf"; Tasks: StartAfterInstall
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to open the user's default PDF viewer, not specifically Acrobat Reader (e.g. I'm not having Acrobat Reader installed and I wouldn't personally install it because you want to show a readme file) ?

Comment: That is excellent suggestion, do you know how to find out the default reader?

Answer (score 15):

Prefer opening your PDF file in the user's default PDF viewer. That's what you can do when you specify the [`shellexec`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=shellexec) flag in the [`[Run]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) section entry for your PDF file. This flag will let your file be opened by the Windows Shell which will use the application registered for the PDF extension:

```
[Tasks]
Name: StartAfterInstall; Description: Display the PDF Readme File

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\readme.pdf"; Tasks: StartAfterInstall; Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works like a charm and is very elegant.

Comment: Anyway, if this answer resolved your problem, you might consider to accept it [`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). You can change your decision and accept another (even your own) answer whenever you want. Thanks!