# How to open a PDF with Inno Setup on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup

How do you open PDFs from an Inno Setup installer on Windows 10? I'm trying to display help documents, and the technique that I use ([based on comments on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733015/inno-setup-how-to-launch-adobe-reader-and-display-a-pdf)) and that works for Windows 7 results in nothing happening when running on Windows 10 (file doesn't open, and no error message is reported).

Specifically, when trying to open a PDF (either before installation in a custom code section using `ShellExec()` or after installation in the `[Run]` section using the `shellexec` flag) in a installer that requires elevated privileges, it will spawn 2 Adobe processes, but no windows will open (and furthermore, no other PDFs can be opened until those processes are manually killed). However, the PDF will open if:

1. Another PDF is already open,
2. The installer was launched from an already-elevated command prompt, or
3. The installer was lanuched from Inno Setup Studio

In all other situations, the PDF will not launch (and until you kill the 2 Adobe processes, no other PDF will open).

This is essentially the code that works on Windows 7 but not Windows 10:

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFile('test.pdf');
ShellExec('open',
  AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test.pdf')), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

Comment: Chances are that there is no shell command registered for the verb **open** when running as an admin. Did you try just passing `''` instead of open? (This would also explain why `ShellExecAsOriginalUser` works when `ShellExec` does not - the non-admin has the open verb action assigned for PDF files.) The default for newer Acrobat Reader versions is *Read*, not *Open*, and using an empty string will cause it to use the default action.

Comment: No luck, passing `''` to `ShellExec` has the same result. However, that's good to know that _read_ is the new default action, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that something is going on with privileges, since the result is different depending on how the installer is launched (e.g. from an already elevated process vs. elevating after starting).

Using `ShellExecAsOriginalUser` works. e.g.:

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFile('test.pdf');
ShellExecAsOriginalUser('open',
  AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test.pdf')), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

I don't know if it is a bug or intended functionality that `ShellExec` doesn't work for this purpose on Windows 10 and `ShellExecAsOriginalUser` does.

Comment: You should have used the `ShellExecAsOriginalUser` from the very beginning anyway. You do not want to run any application with elevated privileges, unless the application requires it. And PDF viewer does not.